# How to update my Ubuntu Software Center App

Tags: software-center, application-development

Ok so I programmed an app (GibberEng) and submitted it to the app store and it got published and all that. How do I make an update to that app. So that all the 80 people who have downloaded it receive the update?

Answer (score 0):

You must submit the new version to the app store, via the [My Apps portal](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/).